# Not able to Get PM2 Logs using the Promtail and Grafana

Tags: logging, grafana, pm2, grafana-loki

The below is my promtail-config.yml which I am running using docker and using this configuration I am able to get Nginx Logs but not the PM2 Logs.

```
server:
  http_listen_port: 9080
  grpc_listen_port: 0

positions:
  filename: /tmp/positions.yaml

clients:
  - url: http://loki:3100/loki/api/v1/push

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: pm2 logs
    static_configs:
      - targets:
          - 435.1248.43.43
        labels:
          job: pm2 logs
          __path__: /var/log/pmx/*log

  - job_name: gcp-nginx-logs
    static_configs:
      - targets:
          - 435.1248.43.43
        labels:
          job: nginx-logs
          __path__: /var/log/nginx/*log
```

I am able to get the Nginx Logs but not the PM2 Logs and I was expecting to get PM2 Logs as well.

Answer (score 0):

It it due to the nature of the logs and how they are generated. Nginx access logs keep track of HTTP requests made to the Nginx server while, on the other hand, PM2 logs are application-specific logs produced by your Node.js apps and maintained by PM2. For example, PM2 logs might have a custom format that matches the output of your application.

I am not sure the format of your application log, however I can give you an example below for a regex to capture the **timestamp**, **log level**, and **ID** from these log lines as these are mostly common in every set of an application log.

```
2023-07-10 12:34:56 [INFO] - Application started: ID=12345, Version=1.2.3
```

```
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: pm2 logs
    static_configs:
      - targets:
          - 435.1248.43.43
    pipeline_stages:
      - match:
          selector: '{job="example_logs"}'
        stages:
          - regex:
              expression: '^(?P<timestamp>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}) \[(?P<level>\w+)\] - Application started: ID=(?P<id>\d+)'
```

In this example, the expression field contains the regular expression pattern. The `(?P<name>pattern)` syntax is used to capture named groups within the pattern.

Explanation of the Expression:

- `'^'`: Start of line anchor.
- `'(?P<timestamp>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})'`: Captures the timestamp in the format `'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'`.
- `'\[(?P<level>\w+)\]'`: Captures the log level within square brackets.
- `'Application started: ID=:'` Matches the fixed string.
- `'(?P<id>\d+):'` Captures the ID (a sequence of digits).

Since the PM2 logs have custom formats, you would need different parsing configurations in Promtail to capture the relevant data. You might need to adjust the regular expressions or log parsing rules in Promtail to correctly process the PM2 logs.

It's important to understand the unique characteristics of the logs you're dealing with and tailor your log processing setup accordingly.